# Unable to resolve these errors?

Tags: android

/*These are the errors occurring while building the project any help regarding it to resolve it thanks.
Add while building project it take to much time and after downloading these errors are showing */

```
 ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0.

    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0.

    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0.
```

Build.gradle(App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sherry.fitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle(project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

/* these above are the files of dependencies i just put these and these error are occurring thankful your help and sorry to not and fully details if not described the question properly*/

Comment: Check to make sure your Android Studio gradle isn't running in `Offline Mode`

Comment: @AdvaitS the gradle is not running in Offline Mode any other help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rebuild the project ad these errors resolved, It's fun, And the Internet should also connected... :P